# Any type can be cast to number map in Typescript

Tags: typescript

It seems like typescript allows casting any type to a map with key of type `number`. Here is an example code:

```
type NumberMap = {
  [key: number]: string
}

type AnyType = {
  foo: string
  bar: boolean[]
}

const anyTypeObj: AnyType = { foo: "foo", bar: [false] }

const numberMap: NumberMap = anyTypeObj
```

I expect the last line to give me a type error when trying to assign `AnyType` to `NumberMap`, but it doesn't. However, assigning an object literal directly to a variable of type `NumberMap` works as expected and causes a type error:

```
const numberMap: NumberMap = { foo: "foo", bar: [false] }
```

Here is a [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NumberMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AnyType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20anyTypeObj%3A%20AnyType%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%5Bfalse%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numberMap%3A%20NumberMap%20%3D%20anyTypeObj%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numberMap2%3A%20NumberMap%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%5Bfalse%5D%20%7D) with the above code on typescript playground.

Why does typescript allow casting objects of any type to `NumberMap`? 
Is there anything special about the type `{ [key: number]: string }` that makes it behave this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript does some extra checking when an object literal is assigned to a varibale. This is called [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). The idea is that an object literal that is assigned to a variable whose type does not have exactly the same properties is likely to be a mistake. On the other hand reassignments and argument values that are not exact matches are common in Javascript, so inexact assignments are allowed when the right-hand expression is not an object literal as long as the value's type is compatible with the variable's type.

In your example `anyTypeObj` is compatible with `NumberMap`. You can treat `anyTypeObj` as an empty `NumberMap`. The contract for `NumberMap` specifies that if you access a property by a numeric key the result will be a string. `anyTypeObj` has no numeric keys, so there is no case where that will not be true.

Note that once you have assigned `anyTypeObj` to `numberMap` you should not be able to access the `foo` or `bar` properties via `numberMap`, because the `NumberMap` type does not declare those properties.

Edit: margaretkru followed up with this question:

> why doesn't `{ [key: number]: string }` enforce that all keys on an object must be of type `number` and values `string`? because `anyTypeObj` has properties with `string` keys so I would expect cast to `NumberMap` fail in that case.

My explanation is that a variable can accept any value with a type that is [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with the variable's type. I think of compatibility in terms of subtypes. For example:

```
const a: Animal = new Cow()
```

That works if `Cow` is a subclass of `Animal` even if `Cow` has properties that `Animal` does not.

In object-oriented languages types are either classes or interfaces, and type `B` is only considered a subtype of `A` if `B` explicitly extends or implements `A`. But some languages (including Typescript) take a more general view. The most general definition of "type" is a description of a set of possible values that satisfy certain criteria. `B` is a subtype of `A` if `B` describes a set of values that is a subset of the set that `A` describes. It does not matter whether or not `B` names `A` in its definition.

`NumberMap` describes the set of all objects whose numeric properties all have type `string`.

`AnyType` is a subtype of `NumberMap` because all of its numeric properties have type `string`. (This is trivially true because `AnyType` has no numeric properties). The string properties on `AnyType` do interfere with `NumberMap`'s contract because `NumberMap` does not say anything about string properties.

Comment: Correct, thanks. I read the docs multiple times and still didn't notice it

Comment: thanks, that explains some part of my question. but why doesn't `{ [key: number]: string }` enforce that all keys on an object must be of type `number` and values `string`? because `anyTypeObj` has properties with `string` keys so I would expect cast to `NumberMap` fail in that case.

Comment: A variable accepts any value with a type that is [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with the variable's type. I think of compatibility in terms of subtypes. This works: `const a: Animal = new Cow()` if `Cow` is a subclass of `Animal` even if `Cow` has properties that `Animal` doesn't. In Typescript subtypes do not have to be subclasses. `AnyType` is a subtype of `NumberMap` because all of its numeric properties have `string` type (trivially true because it has no numeric properties). The extra props don't interfere with `NumberMap`'s contract.

Comment: oh, now I get it, finally :) thanks for the explanation! I think your last comment could be included in the answer, it clarified some things for me.

Comment: @margaretkru Ok, I will update the answer. I'm glad to help!